# Use list comprehension to return number of integers which contain a digit

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

For an assignment I have been asked to re-write the following function using list comprehension. This function takes in a list of integers and an integer digit `a` and returns the number of integers in the list which contain the digit `a`.

e.g.

```
count [102,41,256] 2
```

Should return `2`

```
count [98,4,376] 2
```

Should return `0`

This is what I have for the non-list comprehension function:

```
split :: Int -> [Int]
split 0 = []
split x = split (div x 10) ++ [rem x 10]

checkDigits :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
checkDigits [] y = 0
checkDigits (x:xs) y
    | x == y = 1 + (checkDigits xs y)
    | otherwise = checkDigits xs y

count :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
count [] a = 0
count (x:xs) a 
    | (checkDigits (split x) a) > 0 = (checkDigits (split x) a) + (count xs a) 
    | otherwise = count xs a
```

Split will take in an integer and return the integer in a list

```
split 321    will return:    [3,2,1]
```

`checkDigits` counts the number of times that a digit appears in an integer (this was to solve an error where `count [22] 2` would return as `0` when it should return `2`)

```
e.g. the digit '2' appears 4 times in the list [2,65,42,22]
```

Finally in count we use `checkDigits` to check if any of the digits in `x` are equal to `a`, if this number is greater than 0 (1 or more are equal to a) then add the number of digits found and call again.

I am new to list comprehensions and have only managed to get it to work if the number in the list is equal to `a`:

```
countD :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
countD intL a = length [y | y <- intL, y == a]
```

Here `countD [2,3,4,22] 2` returns `1`l how do I change what I have so that it will return `3` (as there are 3 `2`'s in the list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best I could do. <strike>I'd appreciate if someone showed me how to pass the integer `2` digit as an argument rather than it hard coded</strike>.

Thanks Erik for your answer.

```
countDigits :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
countDigits xs d = sum [1 | n <- (concat . map show) xs, n == d']
    where d':[] = show d
```

Comment: How about `countDigits xs d = sum [1 | n <- concat $ map show xs, n == d'] where d':[] = show d` if you want to pass in the digit and convert it from `Int` to `Char` as in my solution.

Comment: Thanks Allik, that took me a minute to understand though.

Comment: Well and it has the advantage of requiring `d` to be a single-digit integer because otherwise `d':[]` will fail to match the result. Ideally though, instead of using `Int` to specify a `Digit`, there'd be a separate `Digit` type (not an alias) whose constructors are the digits 0 to 9, but in a non-dependently-typed language this won't look ideal.

Comment: You can also use the fact that the List monad uses `concatMap` as `>>=` to write the even less comprehensible `sum [1 | n <- show =<< xs, n == d]`.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a type signature, as your solution (correctly) has a slightly different type than the examples in the question.

Comment: How's it slightly different? `[Int] -> Int -> Int` is what I got. @rampion.

Comment: Ori: `n == d` constrains `n` and `d` to be of the same type. Since `n` is a `Char`, so must `d` be.   I suspect you meant to do `n == d'` to get `[Int] -> Int -> Int`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  Updated

Answer (score 3):

Use `checkDigits` and `split` in `countD`. This is how you count the number of integers that contains the digit (two, in your example):

```
countD intL a = length [y | y <- intL, (checkDigits (split y) a) > 0]
```

And here is how you count the total times the digit appears (three in your example):

```
countD intL a = sum [checkDigits (split y) a | y <- intL]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is ambiguous about what the `count` function should do precisely. At the beginning you say

> the number of integers in the list which contain the digit

whereas later on you say

> `count [22] 2` /.../ should return 2

which is *not* the number of integers that contain the digit `2` in `[22]` — there is only one integer in that list, so you should return 1, regardless of the fact that this integer contains the digit `2` twice.

Therefore, I've provided solutions to both possibilities below.

---

For the first possibility, this solution is the shortest I could come up with:

```
-- these are optional
type Digit  = Int
type Number = Int
type Count  = Int

count :: [Number] -> Digit -> Count
count xs d = sum [count' x | x <- xs]  -- same as `sum $ map count' xs`
  where count' x = if d' `elem` show x then 1 else 0
        d':[] = show d
```

If, however, the 2nd possibility is indeed correct and `count [22] 2` should return `2`, then change the `count'` helper function accordingly:

```
count :: [Number] -> Digit -> Count
count xs d = sum [count' x | x <- xs]
  where count' i = length $ filter (== d') (show i)
        d':[] = show d
```

Comment: Apologies I tried my best to explain it. The correct way was that it should count how many time the actual digit appears in the list.  e.g.
count [102,45,256,24] 2 would return 3. This is because the digit '2' appeared three times in the list.

Comment: [Update] I actually re-read over the brief and realised that I had misread what it said and your first point was actually correct. Apologies about that. Also could you explain the benefit of defining number, digit and count as type Int? could you not just use count:: [Int] -> Int -> Int?

Comment: Yes, you're right: you could use `[Int] -> Int -> Int` which is also why I added the comment `-- these are optional` above the aliases :) They're just for readability because `Int` is not very descriptive. In a language such as Agda or Idris, you would use much more constrained (and thus descriptive) data types and not just type aliases: the return type would be `Nat`, and `Digit` would be `Fin 10` (which is a `Nat` with an upper bound of `10`); it could even return a proof that the return value is `<= length xs` etc :)